# Using window.onload more than 1 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

if i write this

```
$(document).ready( function () { 
    alert("bla1");
});


$(document).ready( function () { 
    alert("bla2");
});
```

All good, two alert occurs, but if code is

```
window.onload = function () {
    alert("bla1");
}


window.onload = function () {
    alert("bla2");
}
```

second alert not happened, tell someone please, why 2 or more **window.onload** is wrong?

Comment: The second declaration overwrites the first, so you can only declare one function to window.onload, and then call whatever functions you need inside that one window.onload

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You assign something to it. You then assign something else to it and overwrite what is there before.

```
foo = 1;
foo = 2;
// foo is now "2" it is not "1" and "2"
```

If you want to assign event handlers non-destructively, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener). You will need to use compatibility methods to support Old-IE. Such methods are built into jQuery via the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 3):

its like

```
 var test;
 test = 10;
 test = 20 
 alert(test); // 20
```

Your overwriting it and jQuery handles there on load event differently.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use the function addEventListener if you want to achieve the behaviour you want.

```
window.addEventListener("load",function () {
    alert("bla1");
}, false);

window.addEventListener("load",function () {
    alert("bla2");
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
function doOnLoad() {
        alert("hi");
        alert("bye");
}
window.onload = doOnLoad;
```

Answer (score 1):

Robert Hahn has a good solution on his [blog](http://blog.roberthahn.ca/articles/2007/02/02/how-to-use-window-onload-the-right-way/).

```
function makeDoubleDelegate(function1, function2) {
    return function() {
        if (function1)
            function1();
        if (function2)
            function2();
    }
}

window.onload = makeDoubleDelegate(window.onload, myNewFunction );
```

> The makeDoubleDelegate() function would be put in the first JS file,
>   ready for invokation any time. What it does is accept two functions as
>   arguments, checks to see if they exist, and if so, return an anonymous
>   function containing valid, existing functions.
>
> The first time that window.onload is called, window.onload itself is
>   undefined, so what gets returned is an anonymous function with only
>   myNewFunction() inside. On subsequent window.onload assignments,
>   window.onload does exist, so whatever it holds will be wrapped up with
>   the new function. And so the list grows.

Comment: Functions assigned to window.onload in this way never execute. No error, they just plain don't run.

Answer (score 0):

i know my answer is too late,but you can try something like this:

```
function hello() {
    window.alert("hello");
}

function bye() {
    window.alert("bye");
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    hello();
    bye();
});
```