# Added multiple external javascripts to html file, one stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, external

I have following problem:
I have html file, named `index.html`. Then i have two external javascript files, named `algoritmus.js` and `vypis_stavkujusich.js`.

I added two javascripts in index.html's head, like this:

```html
<script src="js/algoritmus.js"> </script>
<script src="js/vypis_stavkujucich.js"> </script>
```

First should insert some information to table in body, second should insert some text below table. Now to my problem: when I add those javascript scripts separately, they work just fine. When I add them together, only SECOND of them work! I checked twice src path,i have them both wrapped in init() function that allows them to start only when page is fully loaded. I really cannot find the solution myself. I don't want to put all the code in one js file, i want to separate them to follow good programming habits. Hope u guys will help me, and sorry for my english (my first post on stackovewflow)

```
index.html
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

<!-- IMPORT JAVASCRIPT AND JQUERY -->

<script src="js/algoritmus.js"> </script>
<script src="js/vypis_stavkujucich.js"> </script>

<title> Virtuálne hry VirGames </title>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

<!-- IMPORT CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>

<script>
var teraz=new Date();
var nastavMinuty=function() {
 var minutyPred=teraz.getMinutes();
 var minutyPo;
 if(minutyPred.length>3) {
  minutyPo='0'+minutyPred;
  return minutyPo;
 }
 else
  return minutyPred;
}
document.write("Aktuálny dátum: "+teraz.getDate()+"."+(teraz.getMonth()+1)+"."+teraz.getFullYear());
document.write("<br> Aktuálny čas: "+teraz.getHours()+":"+nastavMinuty()+":"+teraz.getSeconds());
</script>

<h1 id="main_h"> Virtuálne hry VirGames - s nami vyhráva každý ! </h1>

<table id="tabulka_zapasov">
<tr>
<th> Číslo zápasu </th>
<th> Zápas </th>
<th> 1 </th>
<th> X </th>
<th> 2 </th>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="prava_strana">
Generovať zápasov: <input type="text" id="pocet_zapasov" />
<input type="submit" value="Generovať!" id="generuj_submit" /> <br /> 
Vytvoriť imaginárnych stavkárov:
<input type="text" id="pocet_stavkarov" />
<input type="submit" value="Vytvoriť" id="vytvorit_submit" /> 
<div id="udaje_o_stavkaroch"></div>
<table id="tabulka_stavok">
<tr>
<th> stavkári podali 1 </th>
<th> stavkári podali X </th>
<th> stavkári podali 2 </th>
<th> celkom € </th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="vypis_stavkujucich">

<br id="clear-fix" />

</body>

</html>
```

```
algoritmus.js
```

```js
function init() {

function Stat(nazov,rank) {
 this.nazov=nazov;
 this.rank=rank;
 this.favorit=false;
}

var staty=[];

var brazilia=new Stat("Brazília",9.6);
var anglicko=new Stat("Anglicko",8.2);
var cesko=new Stat("Česko",4.5);
var slovensko=new Stat("Slovensko",2.2);
var polsko=new Stat("Poľsko",4.1);
var ukrajina=new Stat("Ukrajina",4.2);
var spanielsko=new Stat("Španielsko",9.5);
var taliansko=new Stat("Taliansko",8.7);
var madarsko=new Stat("Maďarsko",4.8);
var japonsko=new Stat("Japonsko",5.1);
var mexiko=new Stat("Mexiko",6.6);
var rusko=new Stat("Rusko",5.6);
var chorvatsko=new Stat("Chorvátsko",4.9);
var rumunsko=new Stat("Rumunsko",3.9);
var finsko=new Stat("Fínsko",6.8);
var svedsko=new Stat("Švédsko",6.5);
var island=new Stat("Island",5.9);
var usa=new Stat("USA",7.2);
var kolumbia=new Stat("Kolumbia",5.7);
var venezuela=new Stat("Venezuela",6.2);
var bulharsko=new Stat("Bulharsko",3.1);
var cina=new Stat("Čína",5.5);
staty.push(finsko);
staty.push(svedsko);
staty.push(island);
staty.push(usa);
staty.push(kolumbia);
staty.push(venezuela);
staty.push(bulharsko);
staty.push(cina);
staty.push(madarsko);
staty.push(japonsko);
staty.push(mexiko);
staty.push(rusko);
staty.push(chorvatsko);
staty.push(rumunsko);
staty.push(brazilia);
staty.push(anglicko);
staty.push(cesko);
staty.push(slovensko);
staty.push(polsko);
staty.push(ukrajina);
staty.push(spanielsko);
staty.push(taliansko);

var mena=["Gustáv","František","Kadimír","Herbert","Hugo","Bonifác","Jožko","Sergej","Norbert","Kazimír","Branislav","Semir"];
var priezviska=["Janovský","Papadopulos","NejedzChleba","Krutý","Hlavatý","Ježo","Bujak","Had","Fuk","Metalový","Bulo","Aspirin","Kreken","Kunik","Kukuricudus","Vladis"];
function Stavkar(meno,priezvisko) {
 this.meno=meno+" "+priezvisko;
 this.peniaze=vratNahodneCislo(100);
}

var stavkari=[];

function vytvorStavkarov(pocet) {
 for(i=0;i<pocet;i++) {
  stavkar=new Stavkar(mena[vratNahodneCislo(mena.length)],priezviska[vratNahodneCislo(priezviska.length)]);
  stavkari.push(this.stavkar);
 }


}

var vytvorit_tlacitko=document.getElementById("vytvorit_submit");
vytvorit_tlacitko.onclick=function() {
 var kolkoStavkarov=document.getElementById("pocet_stavkarov").value;
 vytvorStavkarov(kolkoStavkarov);
 var udaje_o_stavkaroch=document.getElementById("udaje_o_stavkaroch");
 for(i=0;i<kolkoStavkarov;i++) {
  var novyStavkar=document.createElement("p");
  novyStavkar.innerHTML=stavkari[i].meno+" bude podávať za "+stavkari[i].peniaze+"€ na "+vyberPodanie();
  udaje_o_stavkaroch.appendChild(novyStavkar);
 }

}

function vyberPodanie() {
 podanie=vratNahodneCislo(3);
 if(podanie==1)
  return 1;
 else if(podanie==2)
  return 'X';
 else
  return 2;
}

vytvorStavkarov(10);

var prvyKurz,xKurz,druhyKurz=0;

var kurzyX=[2.40,2.60,2.80,3.00,3.20,3.40,3.60,3.80];
var kurzyFavorit=[1.40,1.45,1.50,1.60,1.70,1.80,1.90];
var kurzyOutsider=[2.10,2.20,2.25,2.30,2.45,2.50,2.60,2.70,2.80];

var generuj_tlacitko=document.getElementById("generuj_submit");
generuj_tlacitko.onclick = function generujZapasy(pocetZapasov) {
 var kolkoZapasov=document.getElementById("pocet_zapasov").value;
 pocetZapasov=kolkoZapasov;
 var tabulka=document.getElementById("tabulka_zapasov");
 for(i=1;i<=pocetZapasov;i++) {
  var novyRiadok = document.createElement("tr");
  tabulka.appendChild(novyRiadok);
  var prvaBunka=document.createElement("td");
  var druhaBunka=document.createElement("td");
  var tretiaBunka=document.createElement("td");
  var stvrtaBunka=document.createElement("td");
  var piataBunka=document.createElement("td");
  prvaBunka.innerHTML=i;
  druhaBunka.innerHTML=vratZapas();
  if(prvyStat.favorit) {
   tretiaBunka.innerHTML=kurzyFavorit[vratNahodneCislo(kurzyFavorit.length)];
   piataBunka.innerHTML=kurzyOutsider[vratNahodneCislo(kurzyOutsider.length)]
  }

  else {
   tretiaBunka.innerHTML=kurzyOutsider[vratNahodneCislo(kurzyOutsider.length)];
   piataBunka.innerHTML=kurzyFavorit[vratNahodneCislo(kurzyFavorit.length)]
  }
  stvrtaBunka.innerHTML=kurzyX[vratNahodneCislo(kurzyX.length)];
  novyRiadok.appendChild(prvaBunka);
  novyRiadok.appendChild(druhaBunka);
  novyRiadok.appendChild(tretiaBunka);
  novyRiadok.appendChild(stvrtaBunka);
  novyRiadok.appendChild(piataBunka);
 }
}

function vratNahodneCislo(poAkeCislo) {
 var nahodneCislo=Math.floor(Math.random()*poAkeCislo);
 return nahodneCislo;
}

function vratZapas() {
 var favorit;
 prvyStat=staty[vratNahodneCislo(staty.length)];
    druhyStat=staty[vratNahodneCislo(staty.length)];
 if(druhyStat==prvyStat)
  druhyStat=staty[vratNahodneCislo(staty.length)].nazov;
 var zapas=prvyStat.nazov+" vs "+druhyStat.nazov;
 if(prvyStat.rank>druhyStat.rank)
  prvyStat.favorit=true;
 else
  druhyStat.favorit=true;
 return zapas;
}

};

window.onload=init;
```

vypis_stavkujucich.js

```js
function initialize() {
var vypis_s=document.getElementById("vypis_stavkujucich");
var r=document.createElement("p");
r.innerHTML="nieco";
vypis_s.appendChild(r);
};

window.onload=initialize;
```

Comment: I'd say it could be a variable naming conflict. Try wrapping both scripts in (function() { .... })

Comment: I wrapped first in init() {}; function, and second in initialize(){}; function, and let both of them to initialite only after page is fully loaded by window.onload=init;

Comment: Are you also doing `window.onload = initialize;`? You can only assign one thing to `window.onload`, so the last one is the only one that works.

Comment: Please post some actual code, otherwise we're just guessing at how they're interfering with each other.

Comment: I edited my first post and added actual codes.

Answer (score 1):

As GrumpyHat mentioned, you are problably having conflict with variable names in your files.

If you have this code in one file:

```
var a = "hello";
```

And this code in another file:

```
var a = "world";
```

When your code gets executed, the value of A will depend on what file is being executed last. To fix this, you can wrap all of your code with 
`(function() {...})`.

Comment: i checked it again, and all variables are completely different named

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind your events like that. Try

```
function a() {
    alert('loaded')
}
function b() {
    alert('loaded2')
}
window.onload = a;
window.onload = b;
```

What you'll see it's only the second function is triggered.
You have to use

```
window.onload = function() {
    a();
    b();
}
```

Alternatively use event listeners, see 
[Add two functions to window.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683176/add-two-functions-to-window-onload)