# Problem Rendering Multiple CanvasJS charts on one page

Tags: javascript, php, canvasjs

I have a page (stats.php) that calls php pages containing canvasjs scripts for rendering charts on them. I can get the pages (top_airlines.php and top_aircraft.php) that contain each individual chart to render, however, when I try to get them on the single stats.php page only one of them will actually render.

It utilizes JSON, which I am not at all familiar with and am using the example that was given to me by their help desk a couple of years ago. I've attempted to modify the code so that it should, in theory, load the chart. Again, they'll load on their independent pages it's just when I try to call them on a single page together that all code breaks loose.

I am curious to think that maybe it is related to the javascript code for

$(document).ready(function ()`

TOP AIRLINES (top_airlines.php)

```
<script src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
<script src=”https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js”></script>
<script src=”http://globe-trekking.com/vg/includes/js/jquery.canvasjs.min.js”></script>

<script type=”text/javascript”>
window.onload = function () {
CanvasJS.addColorSet(“blueShades2”,
[//colorSet Array
“#074b83”,
“#085a9d”,
“#0a69b7”,
“#0b78d1”,
“#0c87eb”,
“#2196f3”,
“#4daaf6”,
“#79bff8”,
“#a6d4fa”,
“#d2eafd”
]);

$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON(“http://globe-trekking.com/vg/charts/top_airlines_data.php”, function (result) {

var chartAirlines = new CanvasJS.Chart(“top_10_airlines_chart”, {
animationEnabled: false,
colorSet: “blueShades2”,
toolTip:{content: “{name}”},
data: [
{
type: “bar”,
indexLabelFontSize: 22,
dataPoints: result
}
]
});

chartAirlines.render();
});
});
}
</script>

<div id=”top_10_airlines_chart” style=”width: 100%; height: 300px;”></div>
```

TOP AIRCRAFT (top_aircraft.php)

```
<script src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
<script src=”https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js”></script>
<script src=”http://globe-trekking.com/vg/includes/js/jquery.canvasjs.min.js”></script>

<script type=”text/javascript”>

window.onload = function () {
CanvasJS.addColorSet(“blueShades”,
[//colorSet Array
“#074b83”,
“#085a9d”,
“#0a69b7”,
“#0b78d1”,
“#0c87eb”,
“#2196f3”,
“#4daaf6”,
“#79bff8”,
“#a6d4fa”,
“#d2eafd”
]);

$(document).ready(function () {

$.getJSON(“http://globe-trekking.com/vg/charts/top_aircraft_data.php”, function (result) {

var chartAircraft = new CanvasJS.Chart(“top_10_airplanes_chart”, {
animationEnabled: false,
colorSet: “blueShades”,
toolTip:{content: “{name}”},
data: [
{
type: “bar”,
indexLabelFontSize: 22,
dataPoints: result
}
]
});

chartAircraft.render();
});
});
}
</script>

<div id=”top_10_airplanes_chart” style=”width: 100%; height: 300px;”></div>
```

I'm calling them on the stats.php page by using the following located in a certain location on the stats.php page.

Comment: use chartjs library, very easy to use. You can add multiple chart too on one page.

Comment: thanks. I used them for a while but didn't like the styles.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to happen due to overriding of window.onload event. Changing it to jQuery ready / load should work fine in your case. Here is the [sample project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am6ZJqYg9ZmfggxQ1G6aRci5nykS).

You can also try out the ways suggested in this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16683176).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    CanvasJS.addColorSet(“blueShades”,
    [//colorSet Array
        “#074b83”,
        “#085a9d”,
        “#0a69b7”,
        “#0b78d1”,
        “#0c87eb”,
        “#2196f3”,
        “#4daaf6”,
        “#79bff8”,
        “#a6d4fa”,
        “#d2eafd”
    ]);
});
```

PS: dataPoints are hardcoded in sample-project.